# Set local-programs-path relative to $STACK_ROOT

Tags: haskell-stack

On Windows, `local-programs-path` (where GHC gets installed) defaults to `$LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\stack`. I'd like to change that to be `$STACK_ROOT\programs` (like it is on Linux). I can specify an absolute path, e.g. `C:/sr/programs`, but how can I specify a path relative to `$STACK_ROOT`? I can see a few possible solutions:

- There is some general environment variable substitution in Stack YAML files (seems generally useful, but [not yet implemented](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/586)).
- The default could be changed to always use `$STACK_ROOT/programs` on all platforms (which is what I would have expected anyway).
- Relative paths could be interpreted relative to `$STACK_ROOT`.

However, none seems to be available as of Stack 1.3.2.

Comment: There's an old open issue to make the GHC installation path configurable: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/998